# What is wrong with this statement? type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<NotificationSettingEntity>'

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
    List<NotificationSettingEntity> notificationList =
        json['notificationList'] ??
            []
                .map<NotificationSettingEntity>(
                    (ntJson) => NotificationSetting.fromJson(ntJson))
                .toList();
```

I've checked json['notificationList'] is List through runTimeType. and I just want an empty array if null.
Shouldn't this be working?
I've tried with [].

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think that the problem is with the empty array []. Since you specify the type before (List<NotificationSettingEntity>) you can give as a value an empty array to initiate the list. Please, more code, to see it throug. I suppose that the problem is in the fromJson method. If you provide us this method, I believe that we will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `()` to `json['notificationList'] ?? []`.

Because `json['notificationList']` is `List<dynamic>` and `??` only work when it null. So we add `()` to make `.map` alway call whatever json is null or not.

```dart
  List<NotificationSettingEntity> notificationList =
        (json['notificationList'] ?? [])
                .map<NotificationSettingEntity>((ntJson) => NotificationSetting.fromJson(ntJson))
                .toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 List<NotificationSettingEntity> notificationList =
    (json['notificationList'] as List<dynamic>)
            .map<NotificationSettingEntity>(
                (ntJson) => NotificationSetting.fromJson(ntJson))
            .toList();
```

You should use 'as List' when you are fetching list from api